# I need to return a row that has the largest of one value and the smallest of another

Tags: sql-server

The example is this

```
20443204    0.00    10030089    4

20443204    9.40    10030324    3

20443204    13.00   10011672    2

20443204    13.00   10030324    1
```

The result should be

```
20443204    13.00   10030324    1
```

So 4th column needs to be smallest but this is not as important as the 2nd column being the most. So after pulling

```
20443204    13.00   10011672    2

20443204    13.00   10030324    1
```

The query should bring the correct result with the 4th column being 1

What I've tried

```
    select job_employee.job_no, MAX(job_employee.act_hours) hours , employee.emp_no, MIN(job_employee.seqno)  from masdb.dbo.job_employee
    join masdb.dbo.employee on employee.emp_no = job_employee.emp_no
    where job_no = 20443204--example
   group by
    job_employee.job_no, employee.emp_no
    order by seqno desc
```

Comment: Try playing around something like this SELECT job_no,
       hours,
       emp_no,
       seqno
  FROM tablename
 WHERE seqno = (SELECT MIN (seqno) FROM tablename);

Comment: Your question isn't 100% clear (for example, what happens if you have two rows with the same value?  is that possible?).  You should also show what you've tried so far.

Comment: That would work but the problem is that the actual table is humongous. So there are seqnos that are 0 as well. I may try making the from table be a subquery and see if it pulls one job_no at a time for comparison. It may run super slow but it's all I can think of right now.

Comment: Right, and number of rows you're dealing with is also relevant here.

Comment: I'm dealing with 1000s of rows.. But if I can figure out how to pull one result for this one job (There are lots of jobs) I can easily format the query to do the rest.

Comment: Thousands of rows shouldn't be a great issue for SQL .... in any case, did you take a look to my answer? That should do the magic :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query could be soemthing like this:

```
    ;WITH MaxValue (H) AS
        (SELECT MAX(Hour) FROM Table_2)
        ,MinValue(S) AS
        (SELECT MIN(segno) FROM Table_2 WHERE hour IN (SELECT H FROM MaxValue))
    SELECT * 
    FROM Table_2 
    WHERE segno IN (SELECT S FROM MinValue) AND job_no = 20443204
```

Comment: That would work but the problem is that the actual table is humongous. So there are seqnos that are 0 as well. I may try making the from table be a subquery and see if it pulls one job_no at a time for comparison. It may run super slow but it's all I can think of right now.

Comment: For what concerns the performance, i cannot say anything, but regarding the 0 values.. those are not returned if they have a lower hour value

Comment: I ran the it already and it pulled nothing for the job number because there are more than one job number, I'm just using the one because it is a good example for the overall picture yet if it helps I could show more than one job.

Comment: It was not clear you were looking for a specific job_no, in any case I improved the WHERE clause to check only for a specific one

Comment: I didn't see that you edited it I have no idea what you did right there so I am going to study some sql as soon as I get home.

Comment: To understand these you should google for CTE https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx